# Regular Exp. - What should it be?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

This is what I want to search for:

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("4.0.10.121017")]
```

The numbers should be able to be

1. 1-999
2. <strike>1-10</strike>    0-10
3. 1-9999
4. 6 numbers (a date)

I have written this but that aint working

```
@"\[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion\(\""(\d{1}).(\d{1}).(\d{2}).(\d{6})""\)\]"
```

Comment: Please revise your title so it can be useful to future users of this site.

Answer (score 1):

```
[1-9]\d{0,2}\.(?:[1-9]|10)\.[1-9]\d{0,3}\.\d{6}
```

---

**EDIT** (based on question update):

```
[1-9]\d{0,2}\.(?:\d|10)\.[1-9]\d{0,3}\.\d{6}
```

Comment: @user1423277 `@"\[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion\(\"[1-9]\d{0,2}\.(?:[1-9]|10)\.[1-9]\d{0,3}\.\d{6}\"\)\]"`

Comment: if I run the above in my code it wont be a match. 
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("4.0.10.121017")]
Fails

Comment: @user1423277 - Sure it fails, because second number is `0` and you require (read your question) that number to be `1-10`.

Comment: @user1423277 - My answer has been updated to reflect your question update.

Answer (score 0):

just translate your needs into a regex:

```
\[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion\(\"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,4}\.\d{6}\"\)\]
```

Comment: @Ωmega  I just assume that the version should be a meaningful number combination. I didn't look it as a tricky question. If it is, how could you verify the \d{6} is a date? anyway, you are right. making it perfect is always the way to go. deserve -1 in this case. :)

Comment: would it be like this because that aint working:   matchVersion = Regex.Match(strLine, @"\[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion\(\""\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,4}\.\d{6}\""\)\]");

Comment: (1) I would go further with regex optimization for date, but I am not sure if date format is `YYMMDD` or `MMDDYY`; (2) I will be glad to remove my downvote, if you add to your answer some notes regarding your regex weakness or do some more optimization, as the question asks for little more...

Comment: @user1423277 i just wrote the regex, no idea which language you are using, and how to escape characters etc. I suggest that you add a tag to your question, to indicate which technology you are playing with.

Comment: C# sorry. It is exactlly as this I want it 000.00.0000.000000 just have to make it work with C#

Comment: @user1423277 oops, then you need to explain your requirement clearly in your question. e.g. 1-999 is not correct, it would be "any number combination with 1-3 digits."

Comment: 1-999 = any  number between 1-999 for example 311 or 2

Comment: @user1423277 but you said "000" is in your sight too.? 000 between 1-999? anyway, what important is you found your solution here.

Comment: oh I just meant that XXX.XX.XXXX.XXXXXX   nothing should be 0. Like 010 would be wrong but 10 would be right.

Comment: @user1423277 I am lost in your comments.... whatever... Ωmega's answer should solve your problem. accept that and back to your work...Good luck